# How to produce a covering artist->original artist chain from a list of songs by covering artists and their original artist?

Tags: python

What I'm trying to do is, I have a list of artists that have covered songs from the original artists. I want to produce a list of **covering-artist->original-artist** chains, with the aim to find the longest chain.

For example, for this table of covered songs:

| Cover artist | Song | Original artist |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Gyroscope | Monument | Jebediah |
| Jebediah | Raindrops Keep Fallin’ on My Head | B. J. Thomas |
| B. J. Thomas | Song 1 | Mary |
| Mary | Song 2 | Sophie |
| Mary | Song 3 | Lucy |

The chains would be:

```
Gyroscope->Jebediah->B. J. Thomas->Mary->Sophie
Gyroscope->Jebediah->B. J. Thomas->Mary->Lucy
Jebediah->B. J. Thomas->Mary->Sophie
Jebediah->B. J. Thomas->Mary->Lucy
B. J. Thomas->Mary->Sophie
B. J. Thomas->Mary->Lucy
Mary->Sophie
Mary->Lucy
```

I'm sort of almost there, but I can't figure out how to accommodate for instances where there are more than one covering artist (example 'Mary' above in the top two chains).

What I have currently is this:

```
# format: [['Cover Artist', 'Song', 'Original Artist'], [...]]
songs = [['Gyroscope', 'Monument', 'Jebediah'], ['Jebediah', 'Raindrops Keep Fallin’ on My Head', 'B. J. Thomas'], ['B. J. Thomas', 'song 1', 'Mary'], ['Mary', 'song 2', 'Sophie'], ['Mary', 'song 3', 'Lucy']]

def get_artist_chain(orig_artist, exclude_indices=[], ret=[]):
    ret.append(orig_artist)

    for i, song in enumerate(songs):
        if i not in exclude_indices:
            if song[0] == orig_artist:
                ret = get_artist_chain(song[2], exclude_indices + [i], ret)
    return ret

artist_chain_ = []
for i, song in enumerate(songs):
    artist_chain = get_artist_chain(song[2], [i], [song[0]])
    if len(artist_chain) > 1:
        artist_chain_.append('->'.join(artist_chain))
artist_chain_out = '\r\n'.join(artist_chain_)
```

This produces this:

```
Gyroscope->Jebediah->B. J. Thomas->Mary->Sophie->Lucy
Jebediah->B. J. Thomas->Mary->Sophie->Lucy
B. J. Thomas->Mary->Sophie->Lucy
Mary->Sophie
Mary->Lucy
```

How can I produce the top output?

Edit:
Complete dataset:
https://github.com/njminchin/TripleJHottest100Songs/blob/main/SongsList.csv

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using networkx.
You can look at your problem as building a directed graph with the artists as nodes, and there being a connection from artist1 to artist2 if artist1 covers artist2.

```
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd

songs = [['Gyroscope', 'Monument', 'Jebediah'], ['Jebediah', 'Raindrops Keep Fallin’ on My Head', 'B. J. Thomas'], ['B. J. Thomas', 'song 1', 'Mary'], ['Mary', 'song 2', 'Sophie'], ['Mary', 'song 3', 'Lucy']]

df = pd.DataFrame(songs)
df.columns = ['cover', 'song', 'original']

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='cover', target='original', create_using=nx.DiGraph)

nx.draw_networkx(G)
```

[image]

Now, you can go backwards from the leaves of the graph, i.e. the artists that did not cover anybody. You can use recursion:

```
def go_up(G, node, collect):
    
    parents = list(G.predecessors(node))
    
    # base case
    if len(parents)==0:
        return []
    
    # recursion
    for n in parents:
        collect += [n]
        go_up(G, n, collect)

    return collect
```

Now, find the leaves, and trace up:

```
full_tracks = []
leaves = [node for node in G if G.out_degree(node)==0]
for l in leaves:
    full_path = go_up(G, l, [l])
    full_tracks.append(full_path)
```

this gives the complete chains from gyroscope to lucy and from gyroscope to mary.
You can chop these chains up to get all relationships:

```
all_tracks = []
for t in full_tracks:
    for i in range(2, len(t)+1):
        all_tracks.append(t[:i])

all_tracks

[['Sophie', 'Mary'],
 ['Sophie', 'Mary', 'B. J. Thomas'],
 ['Sophie', 'Mary', 'B. J. Thomas', 'Jebediah'],
 ['Sophie', 'Mary', 'B. J. Thomas', 'Jebediah', 'Gyroscope'],
 ['Lucy', 'Mary'],
 ['Lucy', 'Mary', 'B. J. Thomas'],
 ['Lucy', 'Mary', 'B. J. Thomas', 'Jebediah'],
 ['Lucy', 'Mary', 'B. J. Thomas', 'Jebediah', 'Gyroscope']]
```

Edit: if you want to also include the song, you can make two graphs (artist1 -> song and song -> artist2) and then merge them:

```
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='cover', target='song', create_using=nx.DiGraph)
H = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='song', target='original', create_using=nx.DiGraph)
G = nx.compose(G,H)
```

Comment: This is awesome! How hard is it to add the song to the cover artist? 
e.g. ['Sophie', 'Mary - Song 2'] | ['Sophie', 'Mary - Song 2', 'B. J. Thomas - Song 1']

Comment: @njminchin did this solve your question? If so, could you accept this answer?

Comment: Hey mate, sorry for leaving you high and dry! This solution worked with the small dataset, but when I tested this with a much larger dataset, it ended up stringing together the wrong matches, and then life got in the way of getting back to you. I'll see if I can get the larger dataset posted that I was using in the next few days.

Comment: I've edited my OP and included the full dataset

Comment: I'll get you an example of what didn't look right in the next few days